# Different score on Linux compared to Windows... memory trouble?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory

This is my first post here, and I would like apologize for my English.
I'm bad in C++ and I wrote this code without a lot of research in C++.
Despite this I achieved my goal and I have correct results buuut... only on Windows 10 (codeblocks).
When I try debug in Linux the scores are different. For instance, with the following input:

```
5 
5 0 
3 0 
3 5
5 1
3 3
```

On Windows I get the correct result:

```
2
4
5
1
3
```

But on Linux or on https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/ (probably a Linux server?) I get:

```
0
0
5
1
3
```

To my mind, the issue is in memory... but I've been finding faults for many hours without results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int id=0;
    int klucz=0;
    int rodzic=0;
    int idzzerem=0;
    int ilezzerem=0;
    list<int> dzieci;
};
bool spr(node a, node b)
{
    return a.klucz<b.klucz;
}
int ilezzerem(node drzewo[],int korzen,int pom=0)
{
    if(drzewo[korzen].ilezzerem==0)
           return 0;
    else if(drzewo[korzen].ilezzerem==1)
        return drzewo[korzen].ilezzerem + ilezzerem(drzewo,drzewo[korzen].idzzerem);
    else
    {
        while(!drzewo[korzen].dzieci.empty())
        {
            int a = drzewo[korzen].dzieci.front();
            drzewo[korzen].dzieci.pop_front();
            pom+= ilezzerem(drzewo,a,pom);
        }
        return pom+drzewo[korzen].ilezzerem;
    }
}
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int rodzic,klucz,nIloscWezlow,a;
    std::stack<int> P,K,M;
    int i=1;
    cin>>nIloscWezlow;
    node drzewo[nIloscWezlow+1];
    bool klucze[nIloscWezlow+1];
    klucze[0]=false;
    bool niejedn[nIloscWezlow+1];
    niejedn[0]=false;
    while(i<=nIloscWezlow)
    {
        cin>>rodzic>>klucz;
        if(klucz>0)
        {
            klucze[klucz]=true;
            drzewo[i].klucz=klucz;
        }
        drzewo[i].id=i;
        if(i==rodzic&&klucz==0)
                drzewo[rodzic].klucz=1;
        else
            drzewo[i].rodzic=rodzic;
        if(klucz==0)
        {
            drzewo[rodzic].dzieci.push_front(i);
            drzewo[rodzic].idzzerem=i;
            drzewo[rodzic].ilezzerem++;
            klucze[klucz]=false;
        }
        niejedn[i]=false;
        i++;
    }
    for(int k=nIloscWezlow;k>0;k--)
    {
        if(klucze[k]==false)
        {
            P.push(k);
            K.push(k);
        }
    }
    list<node> listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania;
    for (int k = 1;k<=nIloscWezlow;k++)
    {
        node obecny1 = drzewo[k];
        if(obecny1.ilezzerem>0&&obecny1.klucz!=0)
            listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania.push_front(obecny1);
    }
    listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania.sort(spr);
    while(!listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania.empty()&&!P.empty())
    {
        node obecny = listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania.front();
        listaIDPoddrzewDoBadania.pop_front();
        int idobecnego = obecny.id;
        int ilezdjackluczy = ilezzerem(drzewo,idobecnego);
        while(ilezdjackluczy!=0)
        {
            int kluczdowlozeniawM = K.top();
            K.pop();
            M.push(kluczdowlozeniawM);
            ilezdjackluczy--;
        }
        int elementzeszczytu=0;
        if(!K.empty())
            elementzeszczytu = K.top();
        if(elementzeszczytu>obecny.klucz ||K.empty())
        {
            node current = obecny;
            while(current.ilezzerem==1)
            {
                int dowstawienia = M.top();
                M.pop();
                drzewo[current.idzzerem].klucz=dowstawienia;
                if(drzewo[current.idzzerem].klucz==0)
                    break;
                current=drzewo[current.idzzerem];
            }
            int pomDlaP = P.top();
            while(pomDlaP<obecny.klucz && !P.empty())
            {
                P.pop();
                if(!P.empty())
                    pomDlaP= P.top();
            }
        }
        else if(elementzeszczytu<obecny.klucz)
        {
            int pomDlaP = P.top();
            while(pomDlaP<obecny.klucz && !P.empty())
            {
                niejedn[pomDlaP]=true;
                P.pop();
                if(!P.empty())
                    pomDlaP= P.top();
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int koniec = 1;koniec<=nIloscWezlow;koniec++)
    {
        if(niejedn[drzewo[koniec].klucz])
            cout<<0<<endl;
        else
            cout<<drzewo[koniec].klucz<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Different results on different systems for the exact same input, that usually means *undefined behavior*. You might want to make sure that you don't go out of bounds of any arrays. And also learn how to use a *debugger* so you can step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. It helps with debugging if you store intermediate results in temporary variables.

Comment: Seeing different results like that indicates that there's a bug or undefined behavior somewhere in the running code. The shown code is full of unsafe programming practices, like lack of bounds checking, and 1-based array indexing which is a frequent source of bugs.

Comment: Oh, and C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (which all your arrays are). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. And don't learn C++ from so-called "competition" sites, get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take classes instead.

Comment: It's not at all obvious that all the elements of `niejedn` (or the other arrays, for that matter) have determinate values.

Comment: On a side note: drop the habit of adjusting to one-based, closed-interval indexing. It only makes it harder for you to learn the language.

Comment: Alright, i understand, thanks for comments but despite that Can anyone see what I can change in the code to achieve the same on the linux?

Comment: Always initialize everything. Use `std::vector` instead of variable-length arrays. Learn how to work with the conventional intervals; zero-based and half-open.